# RStudio .rd-file - Binomial cofficient in Help file

Tags: r, code-documentation

I just got a minor problem which keeps bugging me:
I'm currently creating my own R package and obviously need some documentation/help files for that. I'm good so far, but I currently try to work out how to use the \choose command in .rd-files. It keeps producing some weird output in the PDF i create via the .rd-files. I currently use it like that:

```
\deqn{P(k \leq x \leq s) = \sum\limits_{i = k}^{s} \choose(s,j)u^j(1-u)^{s-j} }
```

which delivers me

[image: screenshot of incorrect formula]

which is obviously wrong. If I leave out the choose command, I get what I want here (missing the binomial coefficient of course). I tried any combination I could think of as \choose{s,k}, \choose{s}{k} and everything gives me basically the same output. Any ideas?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

choose is odd. try

```
{{s}\choose{j}}
```